# Cannot use __get / __set function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a class inherited from CI_Model as follows:

```
<?php
class DBObject extends CI_Model {
    // fields
    public $errorMsg;
    protected $_columnsConfig;
    protected $_tableName;
    // functions
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    // getter
    public function __get($name) { 
        if (strtolower($name) == "columncount") { 
            return count($this->_columnsConfig);
        } else { 
            $colCfg = null;
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < count($this->_columnsConfig)) { 
                $dbcc = $this->_columnsConfig[$i];
                if (strtolower($name) == strtolower($dbcc->propertyName)) { 
                    $colCfg = $dbcc;
                    break;
                }
                $i++;
            }
            if ($colCfg != null) return $colCfg->storedValue;
            else return null;
        }
    }
    // setter
    function __set($name, $value) { 
        $colCfg = null;
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($this->_columnsConfig)) { 
            $dbcc = $this->_columnsConfig[$i];
            if (strtolower($name) == strtolower($dbcc->propertyName)) { 
                $colCfg = $dbcc;
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if ($colCfg != null) $colCfg->newValue = $value;
    }
}
```

When I run my code, I have an error message:

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function database() on null
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hostelry_pms\application\models\DBObject.php
>
> Line Number: 11

But when I comment the `__get` / `__set` functions, the code can run without problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Side note: this is a really weird looking class. CI already has an ORM for making database queries. You seem to be abusing `CI_Model` to do something it's really not intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CI_Model` has its own `__get` function [already defined](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/b862664f2ce2d20382b9af5bfa4dd036f5755409/system/core/Model.php).

By overriding it (and totally changing how it works), chances are you've broken everything in CI that expects that magic method to work a certain way. `$this->load` is probably one of those now-broken things.

Comment: To be able to use __get and __set function in inheritance classes, I need to call parent::_get in my __get function when the name parameter cannot be found within my code, and doing the same in my __set function.